# referencing a .jpg file in a KMZ is not currently working

Tags: java, kml

I have an ScreenOverlay with an icon that I am trying to all put into a KMZ file and its not finding the icon path.

I have a directory called DIR
Inside DIR I have A.JPG and test.kml file

in the test.kml I am referencing the Icon:
./A.JPG

I have tried all sorts of references and nothing is working. Just a red X on screen where the overlay should be.

What is the correct format for withing same directory as KML file?

To make the KMZ I zip the DIR directory and then rename it to dir.kmz.

I then copy it into Google Earth.

Are there any settings in Google Earth I need to set up also?

THank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

try putting the KML file in the root directory of the KMZ instead of a folder and referencing the image through yourdir/A.JPG

Here's a helpful doc on using KMZs:
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmzarchives